# CakePHP and tinyint as boolean

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I force CakePHP 2.x to retrieve tinyint database column not as boolean but as tinyint?

MySQL:

```
Column        |    type
-------------------------------
...           |    ...
category_id   |    tinyint(1)
...           |    ...
```

CakePHP:

```
$this->request->data = $this->Question->read();
var_dump($this->request->data['Question']['category']);
```

The value is always 0 (if the question I'm fetching as the category id 0) or 1 (if the question has any other category id).

Comment: What do you mean? In case of 0 or 1 it retrieves that value, than its php who converts it to boolean (but that depends on you); if the int is 9, for example, what does it become?. Anyway, you can always cast it to int : `intval($result)` or `(int)$result`

Comment: MySQL tinyint accept value from -128 to 127, I use this type to store categories id in a table. When I ask for category e.g 12, it retrieves 1...

Comment: You should post the code you're using then

Comment: Oh, so it's tinyint(1) you're using...wouldn't that mean the IDs are all truncated after 1 figure?

Comment: MySQL 8 has deprecated integer display lengths. When changing a column in phpMyAdmin, you may unintentionally reset tinyint and confuse CakePHP 2. Run: ```ALTER TABLE `yourtable` CHANGE `yourfield` `yourfield` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;``` Fun, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `TINYINT(2)` instead. If the length is 1, Cake sees it as a boolean.

Comment: If he used `TINYINT(1)` doesn't that mean that all his category ids would be truncated? At that point there's no problem because CakePHP doesn't have the right data to fetch anyhow.

Comment: If he was storing IDs in a tinyint it would truncate them anyway. tinyints are really just for booleans (as far as Cake goes), not for FKs.

Comment: As I said to Damien Pirsy, tinyint has a range of 255. I have 15 categories so I thought it was enough. Is there something i'm missing ?

Comment: @BaptisteCosta Tinyint has that range, unless you limit it, as you're doing

Comment: jeeremy is right - this is the only solution. and also the proper way of handling this type of data in cake!

Comment: In the end, this answers the question. Whether or not the OP is "doing it right" is up to him. If @BaptisteCosta knows there will only be 15 categories, go for it! Save the space :)

Comment: This was driving me crazy!

Comment: Me too! How do i validate it in my model ? With integer?

Comment: @Isengo you can probably use `Validation::naturalNumber`, see: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::naturalNumber

Comment: For whoever reads this and is confused by the "range" comments above:  At the database level the so-called "limit" doesn't change the range of that can be stored in the column, it only changes how the values are returned if `ZEROFILL` is used. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/int/

Answer (score 4):

The proper way (CakePHP3), if anyone is still having this problem

Model\UsersTable.php

```
protected function _initializeSchema( Schema  $schema)
{
    //this is a bigInt(20) field (other same type known Cakephp problem)
    $schema->columnType('OtherField'  , 'string');

    //this is a tinyint field
    $schema->columnType('Type'        , 'integer');

    return $schema;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here giving the way for cakephp4

```
use Cake\Database\Schema\TableSchema;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    protected function _initializeSchema(TableSchema $schema)
    { 
        $schema->setColumnType('my_column', 'integer');

        return $schema;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check here: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-complex-types

Comment: If you see \TableSchema is causing error then you should use \TableSchemaInterface

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me where I casted it before fetching it.

```
$result = $this->Question->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id),'fields'=>array('CAST(Question.category AS SIGNED) as category')));
echo $result[0]['category'];
```