# Cakephp: while inserting tinyint field. Getting only "0" or "1"

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm a noob in cakephp. Working on an opensource project. The issue is:

When I'm inserting a value for a certain table ( "is_adjusted" (tinyint)), the my php code executes successfully. But the table is only taking 0 or 1 as it's value. Sample code :

```
        $reward = $ta_customer_reward->newEntity();
        $string_reward = var_export($reward, true);
        $reward->customer_email = $some_preset_xyz;
        $reward->reward_amount = $some_preset_xyz;;
        $reward->particulars = $some_preset_xyz;
        .. .. .. 

        // This is_adjusted is the culprit.            
        $reward->is_adjusted = 2;

        $reward = $ta_customer_reward->save($reward);
```

Now whenever I save (insert) this in db, this is stored as 1. I'm stuck for three days. Things I've checked:

1. No default value in db for is_adjusted.
2. No other function is overwriting that field.

*** 1.The reward object looked quite unusual to me. There is a property name dirty.  I'm still studying this. But for now it seems to me as some cakephp db object structure.

2. This is cakephp v 3. xyz***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by CakePHP's design. CakePHP always see `tinyint(1)` as boolean hence it will always convert your value to `true`/`false` hence the `1`/`0`.

To overcome this issue, use `tinyint(2)` instead for your column type. Remember to clear your model cache!

---

CakePHP data type documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#data-types

Blog post about this:
http://blog.room34.com/archives/2649

Similar Q&A:
[CakePHP and tinyint as boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801632/cakephp-and-tinyint-as-boolean)

Comment: Indeed, tinyint(2) was always the one people should use to make [enums](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/).

Comment: Thanks Lionel Chan. You're a life saver. As a noob in ckphp, I didn't have the slightest idea that a framework can infer such thing. The blog link was really helpfull. Can't upvote because of my reputation. But thanks a ton !!!

Comment: No worries. Just accept the answer if you think it is indeed answered what you have asked.